# Getting type of property in type extension

Tags: typescript

```
function extractIdFromObject<T extends { id: U }, U>(item: T) {
    return item.id;
}

const x = extractIdFromObject({ id: 1 });
const y = extractIdFromObject({ id: "1" });
const z = extractIdFromObject({ id: {} });
```

I wrote the function above, which given an object that has the property `id`, will return the value of `id`.

Whilst the above will run just fine, the TS engine infers `x`, `y` and `z` to be `{}`.

How must I alter my type in order to receive correct type information for `U` (`item.id`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting Typescript to infer one type parameter based on another doesn't usually work. The simplest solution in this case is to use a type query.

```
function extractIdFromObject<T extends { id: any }>(item: T): T['id']{
    return item.id;
}

const x = extractIdFromObject({ id: 1 });

const y = extractIdFromObject({ id: "1" });
const z = extractIdFromObject({ id: {} });
```